# MySQL Difference Between last two rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, procedure, difference

I Have a simple mysql table with three  columns: ID (autoincrement), Value (float) and difference (float).
Every 5 seconds a new row is inserted adding a Value and NULL in difference column.

I want to set up a stored procedure, triggered automatically when a new row is inserted, which populates the “difference” column of a new record (record n) with the difference between the value of record n and value of (n-1) record.

So each new row (n) difference colum will be value(n)-value(n-1).

Could you help me writing the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

You need build trigger ON BEFORE INSERT into your table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `tablename_BEFORE_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE old_value FLOAT;

    SELECT value INTO old_value FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; 
    SET NEW.diff = NEW.value - old_value;
END;
```

Comment: Hi Slava, Thanks for your help! How do you manage if new value is 0 and I want to have diff = 0? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `IF NEW.value = 0 THEN NEW.diff = 0 ELSE SELECT value INTO old_value FROM tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1; 
    SET NEW.diff = NEW.value - old_value; END IF`